# The text within a String is rearranged after being submitted and returned back

Tags: java

I'm creating a program that takes single any characters between the ASCII codes of 32 - 126 and returns the result as Binary. It's a bunch of *if* statements with .contains("")'s. The code works when returning single characters, but when entering words, the Strings come back in binary re-alphabetized. So if I enter in the name Lauren it comes out in Binary like this: 010011000110000101100101011011100111001001110101-Laenru (capitals come first still).

Here's all my code:

Main.java

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Main {

         public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

         public static void main (String[] args) {

              Letters l = new Letters();

              l.Letters();
         }
    }
```

Letters.java

public class Letters extends Main {

```
@SuppressWarnings("null")
public static void Letters () {
        System.out.println("Enter your letter(s)");

        String givenLetters = input.next();

            if (givenLetters.contains("A"))
                System.out.println("01000001");

            if (givenLetters.contains("B"))
                System.out.println("01000010");

            if (givenLetters.contains("C"))
                System.out.println("01000011");

            if (givenLetters.contains("D"))
                System.out.println("01000100");

            if (givenLetters.contains("E"))
                System.out.println("01000101");

            if (givenLetters.contains("F"))
                System.out.println("01000110");

            if (givenLetters.contains("G"))
                System.out.println("01000111");

            if (givenLetters.contains("H"))
                System.out.println("01001000");

            if (givenLetters.contains("I"))
                System.out.println("01001001");

            if (givenLetters.contains("J"))
                System.out.println("01001010");

            if (givenLetters.contains("K"))
                System.out.println("01001011");

            if (givenLetters.contains("L"))
                System.out.println("01001100");

            if (givenLetters.contains("M"))
                System.out.println("01001101");

            if (givenLetters.contains("N"))
                System.out.println("01001110");

            if (givenLetters.contains("O"))
                System.out.println("01001111");

            if (givenLetters.contains("P"))
                System.out.println("01010000");

            if (givenLetters.contains("Q"))
                System.out.println("01010001");

            if (givenLetters.contains("R"))
                System.out.println("01010010");

            if (givenLetters.contains("S"))
                System.out.println("01010011");

            if (givenLetters.contains("T"))
                System.out.println("01010100");

            if (givenLetters.contains("U"))
                System.out.println("01010101");

            if (givenLetters.contains("V"))
                System.out.println("01010110");

            if (givenLetters.contains("W"))
                System.out.println("01010111");

            if (givenLetters.contains("X"))
                System.out.println("01011000");

            if (givenLetters.contains("Y"))
                System.out.println("01011001");

            if (givenLetters.contains("Z"))
                System.out.println("01011010");

            if (givenLetters.contains(" "))
                System.out.println("00100000");

            if (givenLetters.contains("a"))
                System.out.println("01100001");

            if (givenLetters.contains("b"))
                System.out.println("01100010");

            if (givenLetters.contains("c"))
                System.out.println("01100011");

            if (givenLetters.contains("d"))
                System.out.println("01100100");

            if (givenLetters.contains("e"))
                System.out.println("01100101");

            if (givenLetters.contains("f"))
                System.out.println("01100110");

            if (givenLetters.contains("g"))
                System.out.println("01100111");

            if (givenLetters.contains("h"))
                System.out.println("01101000");

            if (givenLetters.contains("i"))
                System.out.println("01101001");

            if (givenLetters.contains("j"))
                System.out.println("01101010");

            if (givenLetters.contains("k"))
                System.out.println("01101011");

            if (givenLetters.contains("l"))
                System.out.println("01101100");

            if (givenLetters.contains("m"))
                System.out.println("01101101");

            if (givenLetters.contains("n"))
                System.out.println("01101110");

            if (givenLetters.contains("o"))
                System.out.println("01101111");

            if (givenLetters.contains("p"))
                System.out.println("01110000");

            if (givenLetters.contains("q"))
                System.out.println("01110001");

            if (givenLetters.contains("r"))
                System.out.println("01110010");

            if (givenLetters.contains("s"))
                System.out.println("01110011");

            if (givenLetters.contains("t"))
                System.out.println("01110100");

            if (givenLetters.contains("u"))
                System.out.println("01110101");

            if (givenLetters.contains("v"))
                System.out.println("01110110");

            if (givenLetters.contains("w"))
                System.out.println("01110111");

            if (givenLetters.contains("x"))
                System.out.println("01111000");

            if (givenLetters.contains("y"))
                System.out.println("01111001");

            if (givenLetters.contains("z"))
                System.out.println("01111010");
        }

 }
```

I want the String to come out the same way the user will have entered it if that means I have to add code to re-rearrange the letters or that I need to fix something in my buggy code.
Thanks in advanced! :)

Answer (score 2):

try

```
  String givenLetters = input.next();
  for(char c : givenLetters.toCharArray()) {
       if (c == 'A')
           System.out.println("01000001");
....
```

or better create a map

```
    static Map<Character, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        map.put('A', "01000001");
        ...
    }
```

then the code will be

```
 for(char c : givenLetters.toCharArray()) {
       String s = map.get(c);
       if (s != null) {
           System.out.print(s);
       }
 ...
```

Comment: So just to be clear, for every character I would use these lines of code (without input.next(); line of course), I would use a different variable for every character (not using "c" repetitively), and why do you think it would make a difference to be using char instead of String.

Sorry I'm asking so many question, I just want to be clear as to what I'm doing, especially since I'm not half as good as alot of the people out there.
Thanks!

Comment: No.  The `for` loop will will replace the value of c with the first letter, then rerun the loop using the second letter in c, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Two comments:

1) To loop through the characters in the string...

```
for(int i=0; i<givenLetters.length(); i++) {
  char c = givenLetters.charAt(i);
  System.out.println(code[c]);
}
```

2) Make an array with your code to avoid that nasty if statement

```
private static String code[255];

static {
    code['A'] = "01000001";
    code['B'] = "01000010";
```

(and so on)

That allows you to use `System.out.println(code[c])` in place of that huge if chain.
If you want to literally put the binary on the same line, replace `println` with `print`

Answer (score 0):

You problem is that `givenLetters.contains("X")` returns true if the substring `"X"` is found *anywhere* in the string `givenLetters`.  As Evgeniy Dorofeev suggests, what you should do instead is to loop over the characters in the string one by one.

Of course, using a huge list of `if` statements (or even a huge array) is a silly way to convert a character to binary.  Instead, you can do it bit by bit ([demo on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/eBIVOz)):

```
char[] bits = new char[8];
for (char c : givenLetters.toCharArray()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        int bitmask = 1 << (7-i);
        bits[i] = ((c & bitmask) == 0 ? '0' : '1');
    }
    System.out.println(bits);
}
```

(Note that Java chars are actually 16 bits long; this code will only print the lowest 8 bits of each.)